# Restore Webkit's CSS outline on input field

Tags: css

I want to restore the default CSS `outline` setting on some form fields but I want it restored to the default Webkit or browser specific style.

The page I'm working with has `outline: none` applied on all elements, and I just want to revert to the default setting on a few ones. Any ideas?

Comment: FWIW, `outline: revert;` technically works, while Firefox and Safari has implemented it, Chrome has not. See bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=579788.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Instead of resetting with outline: none, reset with outline-width: 0. This prevents the browser from clearing the styles and when you reapply a width the style will still be there.

```
input:focus {
  outline-width: 0;
}

input.nostyle:focus {
  outline-width: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VT4Hb/

Comment: Although this is not the actual answer, it is a very good solution that works. Thanks!

Comment: The modern way would be to do `outline: initial`

Comment: But `outline: initial` is not working as expected. Actually it does nothing. :-(

Answer (score 57):

The answer to your actual question ([straight from WebKit's default `html.css` styles](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css#L939)) is this:

```
:focus {
    outline: auto 5px -webkit-focus-ring-color;
}
```

The value of `-webkit-focus-ring-color` is determined on each platform separately (if you're super keen, you can look for `WebCore::systemFocusRingColor`). In practice, the values vary by platform.

In Safari v6 and Chrome v20 on OS X Lion, the actual value is:

```
outline: rgb(94, 158, 215) auto 5px;
```

…and in Chrome v20 on Windows and Chromium v18 on Linux, the value I got was:

```
outline: rgb(229, 151, 0) auto 5px;
```

As described in [this great StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7539981/181495), you can [run this jsFiddle to calculate the outline colour on your own machine](http://jsfiddle.net/wx5s7/).

Comment: This should be the selected answer, although duopixel does offer some good insights.

Answer (score 4):

use a class on the fields you want without an outline.

```
.nool { outline: none; }
```

Comment: OneOfOne is correct. CSS does not allow you to "undo" styles. If you can, remove whatever css rule is applying "outline:none" to every element and use a class to specifically target which form elements should not have an outline.

Comment: @jbarreiros: Even though it works, it's not an elegant or semantic solution to put classes on everything. Duopixel's solution accomplishes this using pure CSS.