# What is -webkit-focus-ring-color?

Tags: css, webkit

I want to reproduce the `outline` effect for focused input boxes in webkit to non-webkit browsers. I found [here](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/css/html.css) the default CSS used in webkit. The lines of interest are:

```
:focus {
    outline: auto 5px -webkit-focus-ring-color
}
```

I tried making a search in the whole code for the definition `-webkit-focus-ring-color` [here](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#search/&q=%22-webkit-focus-ring-color%22&exact_package=chromium&type=cs) but could  not find it anywhere.

Comment: Well, the "focus ring" is a rounded gradient which as far as I know of cannot be defined in outline. It looks more like a box-shadow to me. That's how I would personally recreate the effect with something like `box-shadow: 0 0 2px <color>`

Comment: IT also depends on the the user's preferences. On a Mac, it will be either blue or graphite and on a PC, it will be a goldenrod color.

Comment: Use Chrome DevTools. Force element's focus state and [see for yourself](https://i.imgur.com/hkEnWUw.png).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`-webkit-focus-ring-color` is defined in the WebKit codebase as `focusRingColor` in each `RenderTheme` class. That work was performed in June 2009 as part of [this changeset by Jeremy Moskovich](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/45285).

For instance, the default Mac theme (used by Safari) defines the colour in [`RenderThemeMac.mm`](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/rendering/RenderThemeMac.mm#L472) (in a roundabout way) as:

```
[NSColor keyboardFocusIndicatorColor]
```

([Apple's very light documentation of that property is available online](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSColor/keyboardFocusIndicatorColor)).

There is an override value for the Mac (called `WebCore::oldAquaFocusRingColor`) to be used for testing (near as I can tell it's for the code to be able to perform comparison between the browser rendering and a reference graphic; it is toggled using `WebCore::usesTestModeFocusRingColor`). It's defined in [`ColorMac.mm`](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/platform/graphics/mac/ColorMac.mm#L40) as the following (which apparently maps to `Color(125, 173, 217)`):

```
0xFF7DADD9
```

Chromium/Chrome defines the colour in [`RenderThemeChromiumSkia.cpp`](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/rendering/RenderThemeChromiumSkia.cpp#L155) as:

```
Color(229, 151, 0, 255)
```

The default colour (specified in [`RenderTheme.h`](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/rendering/RenderTheme.h#L159)) is pure black:

```
Color(0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 16):

`-webkit-focus-ring-color` does not work in Firefox. You can use the system color `Highlight` as a replacement though.

```
:focus {
    outline: auto 2px Highlight;
    outline: auto 5px -webkit-focus-ring-color;
}
```

Also see [this](http://www.outlinenone.com/) site on why resetting `outline` styles is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks, it's annoying when Bootstrap reset `outline` by default. I wish I could simply use `outline: inherit/initial` to re-reset it.

Comment: I agree with Bootstrap resetting it being annoying... which is why we then have to try to "un-"reset it to bring it back to as close to the browser default as we can, because you cannot un-reset something once it's set. I was also hoping initial/inherit would have worked, but neither does.

Comment: regarding system colors: [“Authors must not use these keywords.”](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#system-colors)

Comment: [Looks like `Highlight` has been un-deprecated by the W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#deprecated-system-colors)

Answer (score 11):

Use this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wx5s7/). I got `rgb(229, 151, 0)` in Chrome 14 on Windows 7.

Comment: I got `rgb(94, 158, 214)` in Chrome 14 on Mac OS X. Lol.

Comment: Well, yeah, Mac input fields by default are a blue color. You can change it to graphite. But on Windows (and I think Ubuntu as well), the outline is gold. I believe the gold color is Webkit's default color and I think Macs override that (but I may be incorrect about that). Did this answer your question? (By the way, in Chrome 12 on Mac OS 10.6, I got `rgb(97, 157, 215)`.)

Comment: And on Macs, the outline is a gradient and others it is not.

Comment: `rgb(59, 153, 252)` in the current version.

Answer (score 6):

FWIW:
Using Chrome on a Mac, I get a blue outline color when using normal browser mode. When I use the device view, I get a yellow/golden outline color.

Not sure why it changes - was actually very confusing. See examples below.

[image: device-enabled, yellow outline]

[image: normal-browser, blue outline]

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 6):

The following code tries to find the closest solution to the system colors:

```css
*:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px rgba(59, 153, 252, .7);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px activeborder; /* Blink, Chrome */ 
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px -moz-mac-focusring; /* Firefox */
    outline: auto 0 -webkit-focus-ring-color; /* Webkit, Safari */
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays, the [`revert` value](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade-4/#default) has good [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-revert-value) (yay!), which is used to roll back to the default UA styles, here's my 2020 "please let me have outlines" snippet (usually accompanied with `!important` declarations):

```
:focus {
  outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto thin;
  outline: revert;
}
```

Or if you wish to use longhand properties for the first instance of `outline`:

```
  outline-color: -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-style: auto;
  outline-width: thin;
  outline: revert;
```