# What is the default style of the blue focus outline in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, contenteditable

I have a webapp that uses contenteditable div's. I like how they appear in Chrome: when I focus, Chrome displays a nice blue glow around the div. However in Firefox I get an ugly dashed outline. 
What I observed so far is that Chrome stops displaying its default blue frame once I change the outline of div:focus.
I'd like to make my app consistently look nice, so my question is

how can I replicate Chrome's default style for `div[contenteditable="true"]:focus`?

Comment: it's more helpful to know how to find it: in devtools, force :focus state on the div, and see the styles

Answer (score 80, accepted):

To answer the question, Webkit browsers use `outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;`. On Macs `-webkit-focus-ring-color` is blue `rgb(94, 158, 214)` (or `#5E9ED6`), but on Windows and Linux it’s gold `rgb(229, 151, 0)` (or `#E59700`) ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538771/what-is-webkit-focus-ring-color)).

While I understand your desire for consistency, users generally only use one browser, and are used to their browser’s default styles. Note that unless you plan to change every instance of `:focus` you’ll end up with inconsistency for e.g. keyboard users. Pros and cons eh!

If you define `outline` styles and want to ‘revert’ back to the default User Agent styles on `:focus`, this will help

```css
.myClass:focus {
  outline: 1px dotted #212121;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
}
```

```html
<input class="myClass" />
```

The `-webkit`-prefix color means FF, IE and Edge will ignore the second rule and use the first. Chrome, Safari and Opera will use the second rule.

HTH!

Comment: This seems to be old, as it is now box-shadow.  Do you know the value today?

Answer (score 6):

This [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CXUpm/916/) gives a good approximation, you may want to tweak to get closer to what you're specifically after though.

HTML

```
<div contenteditable='true'>Edit Me</div>
```

CSS

```
div[contenteditable=true] {
    width:200px;
    border:2px solid #dadada;
    border-radius:7px;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:5px;
    margin:10px;    
}

div[contenteditable=true]:focus { 
    outline:none;
    border-color:#9ecaed;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #9ecaed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks great! I still leave the question open, since this needs rounded borders and does not keep the original borders.

Comment: The simplest thing would be to just use the `div[contenteditable=true]:focus` class above. Though it will only work if the original element has a border specified otherwise it has nothing to change.

Comment: this will not work on an element that has `overflow: hidden`, because the shadow will be considered be overflowed.

Answer (score 5):

I think I've found the perfect one, At least for me:

```js
// Beggin
```

```css
button {
  outline: 5px auto rgba(0, 150, 255, 1);
  -webkit-outline: 5px auto rgba(0, 150, 255, 1);
  -moz-outline: 5px auto rgba(0, 150, 255, 1);
  -ms-outline: 5px auto rgba(0, 150, 255, 1);
  -o-outline: 5px auto rgba(0, 150, 255, 1);
  /* Use a border to apply the outline */
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  
  /* Unimortant styling: */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 30%, #fcfcfc 40%, #f8f8f8 50%, #f0f0f0 100%);
}
```

```html
<button type="button"">Outline</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right for SO to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

For Tailwind users, it's different, testing on ^3.1.8. Tailwind override the default focus color.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```css
.myClass:focus {
  outline-color: Highlight;
  outline-color: -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-style: auto;
  outline-width: 1px;
}
```