# Blue border of the button after component opening

Tags: html, css, angular

Today I met a strange problem with the close button in my HTML component. Namely when I am opening component(Details button for the customer) the close button at the beginning is surrounded by a blue border. After clicking anywhere on the component, the border disappears. 
The problem shown in the photo below:

[image: button with blue border]

I was trying to set the option in my CSS class like outline: none but it not brought desirable result. Moreover, when I will duplicate the same component:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"(click)="onClose()">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

only first close button has blue border.

Customer-details.coponent.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"(click)="onClose()">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>

<h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Customer details:</h4>

<div *ngIf="(this.customer$ | async) as customer; else loading">
  {{customer.name}}
</div>

<div *ngIf="(this.customer$ | async) as customer; else loading">
  {{customer.email}}
</div>

<div *ngIf="(this.customer$ | async) as customer; else loading">
  {{customer.phoneNumber}}
</div>


<ng-template #loading>
  Loading stuff in ngIf...
</ng-template>
```

All I want to achieve is not appearing this blue border after component opening. I am not sure if it is a problem with my browser but currently I am using google chrome. Thanks for suggestions on what I suppose to do to achieve a desirable effect.

Comment: set the css property `outline:none;` to the "close" button, should resolve your problem.

Comment: This specifically happens when you use a `button` html tag, if you want to remove the blue border without overriding the default buttons behavior, use a different tag, such as a clickable `div`

Comment: button:focus {outline:0;} will resolve this issue

Comment: Thank you so much for a fast response. My CSS declaration had a mistake and that's why it was not working properly. Thank you one more time for immediate tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Add style="outline:none" to whichever div you have problem with.**

If it's a button you can do like this

**button:focus {outline:none;}**

```
  <button type="button" style="outline:none" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"(click)="onClose()">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
   </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, use below css to resolve blue border line which is due to default button focus style, please refer this link - [What is the default style of the blue focus outline in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609485/what-is-the-default-style-of-the-blue-focus-outline-in-chrome)

CSS to fix this issue :

```
button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good practice to avoid this kind of issue is to reset CSS : https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion. As far as I can see this procedure should be used at the very beginning of the project so as not to mess :)

Comment: Exactly ! A lot of problem solved thanks to css reset

Comment: These are my first steps with HTML, Angular etc. It's a long road ahead of me to learn good practices. Thanks for your commitment.

Comment: Courage, this is a long road but a great one ;) https://medium.com/@vupham2909/beating-the-steep-learning-curve-for-angular-76fed11131e6