# document.getElementById('').focus() not working on button

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I meet an issue when implementing accessibility features.

I tried to set keyboard focus on a button using the approach:

`document.getElementById('123').focus()`

But, it doesn't work. The element didn't get focused. Can I get some help? Thanks!

JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dp5x7rbq/

Comment: It is working fine, add `button:focus { background: red }` as CSS and you will see the effect.

Comment: @kevinzf it seems you are missing the point. The button element gets the focus as expected but the way you want that focus to show off depends on the css rule you decide to apply explicitely. You were suggested to use `background: red` but you could use any style you prefer just changing the css properties in that rule addressed by the selector `button:focus`

Comment: usually the focus affects the border so you could use something like this: `button:focus{ border-color: #86b7fe;outline: 0;box-shadow: 0 0 0 .15rem rgba(13,110,253,.25); }` but that's an arbitrary choice

Comment: by the way to give some credit, if you press TAB instead of using js to give focus, it gets showed somehow even with no css rule. I didn't notice that before. Maybe this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible could be of help? It's the first time I realize that

Comment: And here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402576/enable-focus-only-on-keyboard-use-or-tab-press I found some more info about the strange behaviour of browsers when styling elements having focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working, just add to css:

```
button:focus{
  color: red;
}
```

To see the change

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is the keyboard focus which is the rectangle box.

Comment: For this, you need to add additional styles try this
button:focus{ border: 1px solid green; }. OR just use bootstrap

Answer (score 3):

Actually, setting focus on the button already works in your example. You can verify which element has focus by checking `document.activeElement`.

The confusion is about the display or styling of the button’s focus state, which usually is a *focus ring*.

### Make focus visible

Modern browser use [`:focus-visible` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible) to style elements that have focus. That selector takes into account whether the user should see focus or not, for example because they used the keyboard to set focus.

Since you are setting focus programmatically, that browser’s styling does not apply when the button has focus. You need to style the [`:focus` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) yourself.

```
#btn123:focus {
  outline: 1px dotted #212121;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
}
```

See [What is the default style of the blue focus outline in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609485/what-is-the-default-style-of-the-blue-focus-outline-in-chrome)

### Use a valid ID

On a side note, the value `123` for an ID is invalid:

> […] an id must contain at least one character and may not contain any space characters.

See [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, the button indeed retrieves the focus.
Besides adding styling to verify this, you can also move the alert to the first button and press space or enter after pressing the right button:

```
<button type="button" id="123" onclick="alert()"> Find out how</button>
<button type="button" onclick="foo()"> click me to focus on left button</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can focus on button or element using `addEventListener` in javascript as blow example

```js
document.getElementById("123_id").addEventListener("focus", focusFunction);
function focusFunction(){
    //Write your script here
    console.log('Focused');
    document.getElementById("123_id").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Focus Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="123_id">Hello Button</button>
    </body>                   
</html>
```

Comment: This does not at all set focus as requested in the question, but instead reacts to focus being set.