# Focus outline doesn't appear when focused programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, focus

if I have a `<div tabindex="1" id="mydiv">content</div>` I can click on it, it will show an outline, and `document.activeElement` points to this element.

However, if I run `document.getElementById('mydiv').focus()` then the element appears in `document.activeElement` but does not show the outline.

How can I make it show the outline when focused programmatically? I'd prefer not to use a class I juggle around to style the outline into existence, as I'd like it to go away whenever the user takes any action that would blur it.

Comment: Can you add a functioning example? (or non-example)

Comment: It appears to work here - http://jsfiddle.net/e6vtm75h/ Edit: Seems to work in Chrome; not Firefox.

Comment: How is a div focusable? Guessing Support for ARIA?

Answer (score -1):

I did it this way.

```js
const element = document.querySelector(".the-element-you-wanna-focus-on")
element.focus()
```

```css
.the-element-you-wanna-focus-on {
  &:focus,
  &:focus-visible {
    outline: auto 2px Highlight;
    outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  }
}
```

[What is -webkit-focus-ring-color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538771/what-is-webkit-focus-ring-color/11929801)