# How can I "undo" outline:none; without deleting the rule?

Tags: css, outline

I'm working with a WordPress theme that has applied `outline:none;` to several elements for their `:focus` state. I need to negate this without modifying the parent-theme files, but nothing seems to be working.

Here's what I've tried:

```css
*:focus { outline: inherit !important; }
*:focus { outline: initial !important; }
a, a:focus { outline: inherit !important; }
a, a:focus { outline: initial !important; }
```

I really want to just reset it to defaults, but the only thing that's had any result so far is:

```css
*:focus { border: 3px solid red !important; }
```

But I really don't want to manually set the styles, just let the browsers do their thing.

Comment: my recommendation, is that if you won't be applying the rules to but a select few things, would be to simply create a `nofocus` class and apply it to the elements accordlying

Comment: We can now use `outline: revert`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63756875/9314312.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @soulshined's comment about using a class instead, but the value you're looking for is  `auto`.

Snippet (manually focus it in developer tools)

```css
a:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

#withOutline:focus {
  outline: auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)">A bunch of text</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">A bunch of text</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">A bunch of text</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">A bunch of text</a>
<a id="withOutline" href="javascript:void(0)">A bunch of text</a>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Not sure why I couldn't think of auto, but it's not anywhere on the W3 docs. THANK YOU x1,000,000,000