# Restore Chrome/Safari/Firefox/IE8+ outline on all focus items

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser

We are using some JavaScript libraries that include the dreaded `:focus {outline: none;}`.
I don't want to mess with the libraries because the next time I upgrade the library, my code will be lost.

For example (alas, not the only such library), FlexSlider has the following code:

```
.flex-container a:hover, 
.flex-slider a:hover, 
.flex-container a:focus, 
.flex-slider a:focus  
  { outline: none; }
```

I see that there is a post [Restore Webkit's CSS outline on input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601697/restore-webkits-css-outline-on-input-field), and we in fact use that code.

```
:focus 
  { outline: auto 5px -webkit-focus-ring-color; }
```

However, that leaves our Firefox and IE visitors without outlines. How do I do a cross-browser outline restoration in my CSS file?

I'm thinking I could use jQuery to excise the problematic rule, but that's subject to breaking if they change their library, and won't help visitors who have JavaScript disabled.

I was also thinking I could do:

```
*:focus
  { outline: inherit !important; }
```

but was wondering if there might be unintended consequences, as in a browser having different outline styles for different tags.

You can see this in action on the [San Francisco Municipal Transportation Agency home page](https://www.sfmta.com/) in the slider to the right of the dark green area.

Comment: Hi Charles, can you please include a minimal code snippet in your question that reproduces the scenario you've described?

Comment: Added code snippets to original post.

Answer (score 0):

Found it in Bootstrap

```
a:focus { 
  outline: thin dotted; 
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color; 
  outline-offset: -2px; 
}
```

Not sure about the outline-offset one; that may be a stylistic decision.